# Weird behavior with diff | grep | sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, grep

My goal is to extract those lines in `File1` which are not present in `File2`

Let's say `File1`:

```
String A
String B
String C
```

Let's say `File2`:

```
String B
String C
```

Lines are sorted and my output should be:

```
String A
```

So I wrote this command for it:

```
diff File1 File2 | grep '^<' | sed 's/< //g'
```

which worked fine for my sample files with 10 - 20 lines.

I also tried this command:

```
grep -Fxv -f File2 File1
```

which too, worked fine for my sample files.

**But the problem is:**

It doesn't seem to work for my actual data set which is two files of around 1 million lines each.

What is happening? What have I overlooked? What is to be done?

Comment: doesn't work or too slow??

Comment: doesn't work, gives wrong results.

Comment: Outputs some of the lines even though they exist in both files, which is not what I want. I want the !{intersection}. :)

Comment: why your grep line has space between `File` and `2` ? File and 1 too ?

Comment: wait!! you want the intersection? define your "intersection" pls.

Comment: Okay there are no spaces, This is just representative.
And let me make it clear. **I want the lines in File 1 which are NOT there in File 2.**

Comment: Check for white space (including control chars as introduced by Windows) at the end of the lines that you think should be identical.

Comment: Didn't think about that possibility... Will check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

if this works for your actual files?

Comment: Will try and let you know. Give me 3-4 min. :)

Comment: Hey, this works out better, but I'm still getting a few hundred common lines. :(

At least, this is better though. My diff | grep | sed pipe was giving me a few thousand common lines.

Why is this happening? 
I thought if a program runs correctly on a few lines, it should be consistent with a million lines as well?

Answer (score 6):

This is what the tool `comm` is for:

```
$ comm -23 file1 file2
String A
```

Comment: Will run this and let you know if it works. :) Give me few mins! :)

Comment: No :( This is even worse than `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1` - or at least for my dataset.

Comment: You have an issue with non-printing characters, most likely spaces. Make sure the format of both files have a consistent format before running the command.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be having whitespace issues.

Have you tried:

```
diff -uBb File1 File2
```

From the man page:

```
   -b  --ignore-space-change
          Ignore changes in the amount of white space.

   -B  --ignore-blank-lines
          Ignore changes whose lines are all blank.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are both of your files SORTED? diff cannot work if the data is out of order...
Check:

```
diff -uBb <(sort File1) <(sort File2)
```

NOTE: Incorporating answer by Anew.